# How to refresh only certain records in the materialized view? Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, materialized-views

I've got a query with lots of records. Records always have to be up to date.
So I've thought of creating a materialized view and a job, which is supposed to refresh certain rows only that have been modified (after update trigger).

Is there any examples of how to update data from mat.view by id?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle does that itself, you don't have to write your own code. You'd refresh it **ON COMMIT**:

> A materialized view can be refreshed automatically using the ON COMMIT method. Therefore, whenever a transaction commits which has updated the tables on which a materialized view is defined, those changes are automatically reflected in the materialized view. The advantage of using this approach is you never have to remember to refresh the materialized view. The only disadvantage is the time required to complete the commit will be slightly longer because of the extra processing involved.

Read more about it in [Refreshing Materialized Views](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DWHSG/refresh.htm#DWHSG8363) documentation.

For example,

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW mv_employees
PARALLEL
BUILD IMMEDIATE  
REFRESH FAST ON COMMIT AS ...
```

Comment: I get the following error : `ORA-12054: cannot set the ON COMMIT refresh attribute for the materialized view`. Will it be ok  if I change `REFRESH FAST ON COMMIT AS` to `refresh fast on demand with primary key as` ?

Comment: I don't think so. ON DEMAND means that you'll (manually) refresh the materialized view, i..e "I'm demanding MV to be refreshed, now!". I'd say that you have to fix the error cause.

Comment: @Karina The drawback to `ON COMMIT` is that the refresh becomes part of your original table transaction (insert, update, delete), which adds latency and dependency to your application. If you go with `ON DEMAND` then the MV refresh is independent, but you'd have to schedule it to refresh automatically at the minimum acceptable interval for your need. Depending on how you set the schedule, your MV could have a latency of up to a minute (the smallest scheduler interval) or more.